# Como llamar a métodos exclusivos de una actividad en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

¿Es posible llamar a métodos exclusivos de una Activity en android para obtener los resultados?
Tengo algo de la siguiente manera:

Estoy creando una app para android, y quiero implementar el inicio de sesión con redes sociales fb y google, la de facebook ya funciona correctamente, pero tengo problemas con el de google. Ya que el código que indica la documentación de google lo tengo en una clase que no extiende de `AppCompatActivity` y por o tanto los métodos como `startActivityForResult` o `starActivity` o los `intent` no son reconocidas como métodos. Existe alguna manera de llamar a esos métodos desde una clase que no extienda de `AppCompatActivity`, agradezco su respuesta.

Comment: Hola! Porque no llamas a esos métodos desde un activity? existe alguna limitación?

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible ejecutar estos métodos desde otra clase, por medio del concepto `Delegate` pattern.
Básicamente hay que definir una interfaz `Delegate` que quién la implemente puede estar informado por lo que ocurre en un `Activity` o `Fragment`.

Delegate:

```
public interface GoogleSignInDelegate {
    void contextActivity(Activity context);
    void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private GoogleSignInDelegate delegate;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        delegate = new GoogleSignIn();
        delegate.contextActivity(this);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        delegate.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class GoogleSignIn implements GoogleSignInDelegate {
    Activity context;

    @Override
    public void contextActivity(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Esto se disparará cuando en la actividad se ejecute
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.v("GoogleSignIn", Integer.toString(requestCode));
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        context.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 0);
    }
}
```